# Configure Perforce to only integrate into clean workspace

Tags: perforce

I just did a

```
p4 integrate -r -b Feature-to-Main
```

followed by

```
p4 resolve -as
```

to bring a feature branch up to date. However, I had forgot to commit my changes to the feature branch, so I was asked to resolve conflicts between changes done to Main and my uncommitted changes. Luckily, the changes were not on the default changelist, so I was able to undo all this by reverting the default changelist and choosing "select target" for all conflicts in the remaining changelists.

I do not like this behavior, and I wish that Perforce had not allowed me to execute the first command. Is it possible to configure Perforce to only perform integrations into workspaces with empty changelists?

Comment: I don't think so; integrate is an operation like any other. I know people who create workspaces dedicated for integrations just for this purpose.

Comment: You could write a `pre-user-integrate` trigger and install it in your server, and have it refuse the `integrate` command if `p4 opened` reported that you had opened files. That would affect all users of your server, unless you wrote the trigger carefully to only apply to **your** user and **your** workspace. You could also write your own client-side script that wrapped `p4 integrate`, and made the same check, and then change your habits to always invoke your script rather than the base command.